# How to make SQL query that will combine rows of result from one table with rows of another table in specific conditions in SQLite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have aSQLite3 database with three tables. Sample data looks like this:

**Original**

```
id    aName  code 
------------------
1     dog     DG  
2     cat     CT  
3     bat     BT  
4     badger  BDGR
...   ...     ...
```

**Translated**

```
id   orgID   isTranslated  langID   aName     
----------------------------------------------
1     2           1         3       katze     
2     1           1         3       hund      
3     3           0         3       (NULL)    
4     4           1         3       dachs     
...   ...         ...       ...     ...
```

**Lang**

```
id Langcode
-----------
1    FR  
2    CZ
3    DE
4    RU
...  ...
```

I want to select all data from  **Original** and **Translated** in way that result would consist of all data in **Original** table, but *aName* of rows that got translation would be replaced with *aName* from **Translated** table, so then I could apply an ORDER BY clause and sort data in the desired way.

All data and table designs are examples just to show the problem. The schema does contain some elements like an *isTranslated* column or translation and original names in separate tables. These elements are required by application destination/design.

To be more specific this is an example rowset I would like to produce. It's all the data from table **Original** modified by data from **Translated** if translation is available for that certain *id* from **Original**.

**Desired Result**

```
id    aName  code    isTranslated
---------------------------------  
1     hund     DG         1
2     katze    CT         1
3     bat      BT         0
4     dachs    BDGR       1
...   ...      ...        ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typcial application for the [CASE expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case):

```
SELECT Original.id,
       CASE isTranslated
         WHEN 1 THEN Translated.aName
         ELSE        Original.aName
       END AS aName,
       code,
       isTranslated
FROM Original
JOIN Translated ON Original.id = Translated.orgID
WHERE Translated.langID = (SELECT id FROM Lang WHERE Langcode = 'DE')
```

If not all records in `Original` have a corresponding record in `Translated`, use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

If untranslated names are guaranteed to be `NULL`, you can just use [`IFNULL(Translated.aName, Original.aName)`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull) instead.

Comment: Looks great, now im unable to test it, but i do it as soon as possible, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably list the actual results you want, which would help people help you in the future.

In the current case, I'm guessing you want something along these lines:

```
SELECT Original.id, Original.code, Translated.aName
FROM Original
JOIN Lang
ON Lang.langCode = 'DE'
JOIN Translated
ON Translated.orgId = Original.id
AND Translated.langId = Lang.id
AND Translated.aName IS NOT NULL;
```

(Check out my [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d16b4/4) to see if these are the results you want).

---

In any case, the table set you've got is heading towards a fairly standard 'translation table' setup.  However, there are some basic changes I'd make.

1. `Original`

   - Name the table to something specific, like `Animal`
   - Don't include a 'default' translation in the table (you can use a view, if necessary).
   - 'code' is fine, although in the case of animals, genus/species probably ought to be used
2. `Lang`

   - 'Lanugage' is often a reserved word in RDBMSs, so the name is fine.
   - Specifically name which 'language code' you're using (and don't abbreviate column names).  There's actually (up to) three different ISO codes possible - just grab them all.
   - (Also, remember that languages have language-specific *names*, so language also needs it's own 'translation' table)
3. `Translated`

   - Name the table entity-specific, like `AnimalNameTranslated`, or somesuch.
   - `isTranslated` is unnecessary - you can derive it from the existence of the *row* - don't add a row if the term isn't translated yet.
   - Put **all** 'translations' into the table, *including* the 'default' one.  This means all your terms are in one place, so you don't have to go looking elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for all hints, tho i forgot to mention that this data and tables are just exemplar, in fact database i work with is more complexed. And also i want to inckude original row, if there is no translation, the flag "isTranslated" is required in my design, also original table is required by design